# gitlab parallel:matrix does not run concurrently

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I am trying to get a job to run in parallel within gitlab. I have registered 8 runners on one server and set concurrent=16 in /etc/gitlab-runner/config.toml. I see all 8 runners configured within that file. Below is the beginning of the file:

```
concurrent = 16
check_interval = 0

[session_server]
  session_timeout = 1800

[[runners]]
  name = "gitlab-runner-02-#1"
  url = "http://gitlab.example.com"
  token = "redacted"
  executor = "docker"
  [runners.custom_build_dir]
  [runners.cache]
    [runners.cache.s3]
    [runners.cache.gcs]
    [runners.cache.azure]
  [runners.docker]
    tls_verify = false
    image = "almalinux:latest"
    privileged = false
    disable_entrypoint_overwrite = false
    oom_kill_disable = false
    disable_cache = false
    volumes = ["/cache"]
    shm_size = 0

[[runners]]
  name = "gitlab-runner-02-#2"
  url = "http://gitlab.example.com"
  token = "redacted"
  executor = "docker"
  [runners.custom_build_dir]
  [runners.cache]
    [runners.cache.s3]
    [runners.cache.gcs]
    [runners.cache.azure]
  [runners.docker]
    tls_verify = false
    image = "almalinux:latest"
    privileged = false
    disable_entrypoint_overwrite = false
    oom_kill_disable = false
    disable_cache = false
    volumes = ["/cache"]
    shm_size = 0
```

.gitlab-ci.yml:

```
image: almalinux:latest

stages:
  - build

foo:
  stage: build
  script: sleep 60
  parallel:
    matrix:
      - foo: [a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h]
```

From everything I've read, this should be enough for it to run in parallel. And yet, all the jobs run sequentially. What am I missing here?

Edit:
I've crossposted on gitlab's forum. I will make sure both gitlab's forum and stackoverflow have the answer clearly listed when I find it. https://forum.gitlab.com/t/parallel-matrix-isnt-executing-in-parallel/72095

Update:
I seem to have resolved the issue. I need to do more experimenting, but it appears to be related to another registered runner on a different server not allowing more than one job. I also increased the limit for each individual runner. I need to do more experimenting to understand what actually fixed it still.